# Hiding Toolbar temporarily while scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UITableView` with a `UINavigationController`+`UIToolbar`

I want to hide the tool bar while the user is scrolling the table.
I hide the tool bar using this:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

And to show the tool bar again, after the table stopped scrolling:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

This works fine if I let the table decelerate by itself. However If stopped the scrolling by touching the table this won't work.

Is there another specific delegate function I should be using?

EDIT:
I also tried the methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

No difference.

Comment: try showing back the toolbar in this method `– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` or in `– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`, they should do the trick

Comment: – scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: did it!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method from the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```